# sql where statement with range: how to separate by a comma

Tags: vba, excel, loops, adodb, named-ranges

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to pull info from a range of cells that will be plugged into the "where" clause of a sql statement.  Since it is a where clause, I need to separate the variables with a comma.  For example, my code is:

```
Sub loop()
AB=2
BC=9
Set IDX = Sheets("Sheet2).Cells(AB,BC)

Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
cn.ConnectionString=PORRI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010; DATABASE=LKMJ_intm"

cn.open
set rs= New ADODB.Recordset
rs.ActiveConnection=cn

rs.OPEN "SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, INFO FROM xxx WHERE ID in ('"& IDX &")"
r=1
Do While Not rs.EOF
Cells (r,1) = rs.Fields(0)
Cells (r,2) = rs.Fields(1)
Cells (r,3) = rs.Fields(2)
Cells (r,4) = rs.Fields(3)
Cells (r,5) = rs.Fields(4)
r=r+1
Loop
End Sub
```

Right now, I can't create a range that will work in the where statement without the comma.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this piece of code works per one id:

```
rs.OPEN "SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, INFO FROM xxx WHERE ID in ('"& IDX &")"
```

What you wish to do is make sure that IDX would be translated to a list of codes, for example (1,2,3) or ('a', 'b', 'c').
If the list of codes is a list of integers I highly recommend getting the list of codes like this

```
rs.OPEN "SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, INFO FROM xxx WHERE ID in ('"& IDX &"," & IDB & ")"
```

(whatever IDB is)
and if it's a list of strings and you need to put them inside single quotes parameters:

```
rs.OPEN "SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, INFO FROM xxx WHERE ID in ('"& IDX &"','" & IDB & "')"
```

This is all very confusing with the quotes and single quotes! Luckily the editor here is smart enough to tell me when I got the code wrong :)

Comment: Is it possible to do this is one function?  I have a larger number of cells that I want to pull from, and don't want to put in each cell for simplicity's sake.  Thanks!

Comment: @J.L.M.    Make IDX a string and use the loop (like you did in the second part) to have all the parts in the IN clause. Most important (and difficult): to get all the single quotes right!